# why python dict update insanely slow?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, cpython, python-internals

I had a python program which reads lines from files and puts them into dict, for simple, it looks like:

```
data = {'file_name':''}
with open('file_name') as in_fd:
    for line in in_fd:
        data['file_name'] += line
```

I found it took hours to finish.

And then, I did a bit change to the program:

```
data = {'file_name':[]}
with open('file_name') as in_fd:
    for line in in_fd:
        data['file_name'].append(line)
    data['file_name'] = ''.join(data['file_name'])
```

It finished in seconds.

**I thought it's `+=` makes the program slow, but it seems not. Please take a look at the result of the following test.**

I knew we could use list append and join to improve performance when concat strings. But I never thought such a performance gap between *append and join* and *add and assign*.

So I decided to do some more tests, and finally found **it's the dict update operation makes the program insanely slow**. Here is a scripts:

```
import time
LOOPS = 10000
WORD = 'ABC'*100

s1=time.time()
buf1 = []
for i in xrange(LOOPS):
    buf1.append(WORD)
ss = ''.join(buf1)

s2=time.time()
buf2 = ''
for i in xrange(LOOPS):
    buf2 += WORD

s3=time.time()
buf3 = {'1':''}
for i in xrange(LOOPS):
    buf3['1'] += WORD

s4=time.time()
buf4 = {'1':[]}
for i in xrange(LOOPS):
    buf4['1'].append(WORD)
buf4['1'] = ''.join(buf4['1'])

s5=time.time()
print s2-s1, s3-s2, s4-s3, s5-s4
```

In my laptop(mac pro 2013 mid, OS X 10.9.5, cpython 2.7.10), it's output is:

```
0.00299620628357 0.00415587425232 3.49465799332 0.00231599807739
```

Inspired by juanpa.arrivillaga's comments, I did a bit change to the second loop:

```
trivial_reference = []
buf2 = ''
for i in xrange(LOOPS):
    buf2 += WORD
    trivial_reference.append(buf2)  # add a trivial reference to avoid optimization
```

After the change, now the second loops takes 19 seconds to complete. So it seems just a optimization problem just as juanpa.arrivillaga said.

Comment: You should make a concated string then assign to a dict instead of `+=` a string on a dict.

Comment: Better use the `timeit` module for this kind of benchmarks.

Comment: It's not about `update` but probably some kind of optimization if there's only one reference to given string. Change third loop to `x = buf3.pop('1'); x += WORD; buf3['1'] = x` and there's not much difference in the results: `0.00136399269104 0.00481796264648 0.00717210769653 0.00203800201416`.

Comment: And it's not just dicts. With a list `buf5=['']` and `buf5[0] += WORD`, you get similar slowness. It's the updating that's slow.

Comment: @muru Yep, juanpa.arrivillaga's comment may be right, it's a optimization problem and your test proves that.

Comment: @niemmi Digging the source code revealed that's the optimization CPython is doing internally: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l443

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`+=` performs really bad when building large strings but can be efficient in one-case in CPython.<sup>mentioned below</sup>

For sure-shot faster string concatenation use `str.join()`.

---

From [String Concatenation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#String_Concatenation) section under [Python Performance Tips](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips):

Avoid this:

```
s = ""
for substring in list:
    s += substring
```

Use `s = "".join(list)` instead. The former is a very common and catastrophic mistake when building large strings.

---

#### Why `s += x` is faster than `s['1'] += x` or `s[0] += x`?

[From Note 6](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange):

> CPython implementation detail: If s and t are both strings, some
>   Python implementations such as CPython can usually perform an in-place
>   optimization for assignments of the form `s = s + t` or `s += t`. When
>   applicable, this optimization makes quadratic run-time much less
>   likely. This optimization is both version and implementation
>   dependent. For performance sensitive code, it is preferable to use the
>   `str.join()` method which assures consistent linear concatenation
>   performance across versions and implementations.

The optimization in case of CPython is that if a string has only one reference then we can [resize it in-place](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l443).

> /* Note that we don't have to modify *unicode for unshared Unicode
>   objects, since we can modify them in-place. */

Now latter two are not simple in-place additions. In fact these are not in-place additions at all.

`s[0] += x`

is equivalent to:

```
temp = s[0]  # Extra reference. `S[0]` and `temp` both point to same string now.
temp += x
s[0] = temp
```

Example:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> def func():
...     lst[0] = 90
...     return 100
...
>>> lst[0] += func()
>>> print lst
[101, 2, 3]  # Not [190, 2, 3]
```

---

But in general never use `s += x` for concatenating string, always use `str.join` on a collection of strings.

---

**Timings**

```
LOOPS = 1000
WORD = 'ABC'*100


def list_append():
    buf1 = [WORD for _ in xrange(LOOPS)]
    return ''.join(buf1)


def str_concat():
    buf2 = ''
    for i in xrange(LOOPS):
        buf2 += WORD


def dict_val_concat():
    buf3 = {'1': ''}
    for i in xrange(LOOPS):
        buf3['1'] += WORD
    return buf3['1']


def list_val_concat():
    buf4 = ['']
    for i in xrange(LOOPS):
        buf4[0] += WORD
    return buf4[0]


def val_pop_concat():
    buf5 = ['']
    for i in xrange(LOOPS):
        val = buf5.pop()
        val += WORD
        buf5.append(val)
    return buf5[0]


def val_assign_concat():
    buf6 = ['']
    for i in xrange(LOOPS):
        val = buf6[0]
        val += WORD
        buf6[0] = val
    return buf6[0]


>>> %timeit list_append()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.31 ms per loop
>>> %timeit str_concat()
100 loops, best of 3: 3.09 ms per loop
>>> %run so.py
>>> %timeit list_append()
10000 loops, best of 3: 71.2 us per loop
>>> %timeit str_concat()
1000 loops, best of 3: 276 us per loop
>>> %timeit dict_val_concat()
100 loops, best of 3: 9.66 ms per loop
>>> %timeit list_val_concat()
100 loops, best of 3: 9.64 ms per loop
>>> %timeit val_pop_concat()
1000 loops, best of 3: 556 us per loop
>>> %timeit val_assign_concat()
100 loops, best of 3: 9.31 ms per loop
```

`val_pop_concat` is fast here because by using `pop()` we are dropping reference from the list to that string and now CPython can resize it in-place(guessed correctly by [@niemmi in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42550181/why-python-dict-update-insanely-slow#comment72235959_42550181)).

Comment: I don't think so, `s3-s2` is small, and `s4-3` is much larger in my test.

Comment: @WKPlus so, it's an implementation detail that recent versions of CPython (I don't recall exactly, something like >2.6) optimize `+=` assignment for strings, otherwise it *is* a quadratic time operation. In `s2` I think the interpreter was able to optimize, but in `s3` it isn't, maybe because you are accessing the string as a dictionary value.

Comment: I **really** want to see an answer with analyzing [intepreter code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/stringobject.c#L3885) and proving that in one case preconditions (reference count etc.) are fulfilled and in second case they are not. In a result observed behavior is optimized or unoptimized string joining.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I did one more test, adding a trivial reference to temporary string, and found it slows down the program.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski a look with `dis` might also be enlightening.